# Why are DCGs defined as a compact way to describe lists?

Tags: prolog, dcg

In my opinion, define the DCGs (Definite Clause Grammars) as *a compact way to describe the lists in Prolog*, is a poorly way to define them. As far as I know, the [DCGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) are not only used in Prolog, but also in other programming languages, such as Mercury.
In addition, they are called DCGs, because they represent a grammar in a set of definite clauses (Horn clauses), the basis of logic programming.
So why if an entire Prolog program can be written using definite clauses, DCGs are solely defined as *a compact way to describe the lists in Prolog*?

Note: The doubt arises from the description for the tag [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) given by SO.

Comment: I believe you injected the adjective *solely* yourself in SO's "definition" of a DCG. ;) So what SO says about the DCG is true (to @mat 's point) but that isn't what I'd call complete description of purpose for a DCG.

Comment: Exactly @lurker, that's my point. By "solely" I meant that this is only one of the CDGs benefits, I guess I didn't put right, my bad :)

Comment: No problem. *Solely* would mean it's the *only benefit*, not *only one of*, but just a technicality. I think it does make for an interesting question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [extended info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcg/info) from the DCG tag wiki provides additional information, which I think is both correct and also in close agreement with your first point:

> "DCGs are usually associated with Prolog, but similar languages such
>   as Mercury also include DCGs."

Regarding your second point: Emphasizing the close association with Prolog lists is in my opinion well justified, since a DCG indeed always describes a list, and typically also quite compactly.